# number "out of order" from a list in python

Tags: python

I have a list and I want to return the first number that out of order, 
this is what I've written. and it's not working..

```
a=input("enter list")
out_of_order(a)

def out_of_order(list):
    foundit=0
    for i in list:
        while foundit==0:
          if (i+1 < i):
              print(i)
              foundit=1
    if (foundit==0)
     print("none")
```

for the list [4,8,9,10,2,12,16] It should return 2

Comment: `for i in list` almost certainly doesn't do what you think it does. It doesn't get the index but actually gets the value of the list item. Look into using `enumerate`

Comment: the first number that is lowest from the previous

Answer (score 3):

You are confusing list *items* and *indices*. As it stands, you are testing for:

```
if i+1 < i:
```

which will never, ever be `True` - whatever value `i` takes, `i+1` will be one <strike>louder</strike> larger.

I think what you were trying to do is compare adjacent items by index:

```
for i in range(len(lst)):
    if lst[i+1] < lst[i]:
```

(note that you shouldn't use `list` as your own variable name), but:

- this will give you problems if you reach the end of the list (where `lst[i+1]` will cause an `IndexError`, so you have to either `try` or alter the `range` appropriately); and
- it is not generally considered Pythonic to use `len(range(...))`.

Instead, the best way is to compare pairs of elements:

```
def out_of_order(lst):
    for a, b in zip(lst, lst[1:]):
        if b < a:
            print(b)
            break
    else:
        print("none")
```

You also make a few other mistakes:

- As *@timgeb* points out, your input will be strings not integers;
- You have a `SyntaxError` (missing colon, incorrect indentation) at the end; and
- You are using an integer as a flag, when Python has perfectly serviceable booleans `True` and `False`.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you are getting a string from `input`, not a `list`. You could get a list of numbers from the input like this:

```
inputstr = input('enter comma separated integers! ')
inputlist = inputstr.split(',')
inputnums = [int(x) for x in inputlist]
```

Another thing is that you should not use list as a variable name, because that's already used for the builtin list. Now, assuming that your `a` is a proper list, you want to compare one element of the list with the next element:

```
def out_of_order(lst):
    for i in range(len(lst) - 1):
        if lst[i+1] < lst[i]:
            print(i+1,lst[i+1])
            break
```

Demo:

```
enter comma separated integers! 100,101,102,100,101,102
3 100 # output of out_of_order(inputnums)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a=input("enter list")
out_of_order(a)

def out_of_order(list):
    foundit=0
    for i in range(len(list)):
        while foundit==0:
            if i < len(list)-1:
                if (list[i+1] < list[i]):
                    print(list[i+1])
                    foundit=1
            else
                break;

    if (foundit==0):
        print("none")
```

Comment: Was this supposed to be an edit to the question and not an answer?

Comment: @Jim only some of them - have you actually tried running that?!

Comment: @jonrsharpe, of course not.

Comment: Probably should've left the if(foundit==0) as part of the function....

Comment: @Jim and maybe added the missing colon, removed the potentially never-ending `while` loop, ...

Comment: @jim retracted downvote :)

Comment: @jonrsharpe, oh right. thnks.

Comment: @Jim could you please **test your code**. Try e.g. `out_of_order([1, 2, 4, 3, 5])` and see where that gets you.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in list:
```

This iterates through the list by letting `i` be each element. Naturally, i+1 is never less than i.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used python in a while, but I believe that when you use 'i' it is referring to a number from the list. For your example in the first iteration i would be 4, in the second i would be 8, and so on. Calling i+1 doesn't return the next number in the sequence, it just adds one to it. When you're saying

```
if (i+1 < i)
```

in the first iteration you're pretty much saying if ((4+1) < 4), which is never true.